# Get List of fonts using EnumFontFamiliesEx

Tags: c++, winapi

[image]I used EnumFontFamiliesEx to get the list of system fonts on windows. But somehow in the list I get fonts with Bold appended to them like 'QuickType Bold' instead of just QuickType as I see in the word fonts list. How can I get the list of normal fonts. I use DEFAULT_CHARSET and I tried FW_NORMAL and FW_REGULAR in the weight setting but no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: There is a [KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/978799) explaining a similar symptom. Could you check the registry as told in the KB, maybe QuickType Bold is before QuickType Regular in your registry.

Comment: I looked at the registry and QuickType is before QuickType Bold. I have added the screen capture in my post above.

Comment: It is an OpenType font.  Mapping them to legacy font functions is a bit troublesome, it synthesizes family names to deal with the ambiguity caused by the missing font attributes.  If you want to get the same list that Word displays (an OpenType enabled program) then you have to do it the same way that [Word does it](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd756583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).